# Solving $F=ma$ With inverse square law a la Coulomb and Newton strange solution?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

$F=ma$ for stuff in free fall, like a tiny particle of little mass $m$ falling into a big mass $M$ we solve 
$$
\frac{d^2Y}{dT^2}=\frac{-GM}{Y^2}
$$
which is a  most well known differential equation and studied in massive detail for over 300 years.

Somehow, just diddling around couple years ago, I found a “particular” exact solution which satisfies the nonlinear $\frac{1}{Y^2}$ force but it’s certainly not like the standard constant force solution
 $Y= AT^2 + V_0T + Y_0$ where $V_0$ would be an initial velocity and $Y_0$ some initial height or distance of separation between the masses (or charges if you're looking at Coulomb’s law.)

Anyway, I find curiously that $Y= \mathrm{Const.} T^{2/3}$ satisfies it too!!  If you don’t believe it but are somewhat interested just try it!  I've been trying to make sense of it for a long time. I am a physics hobbyist and won't belabor my efforts, and it’s just a “little ole “ diff equation, nonlinear yes, but if you just *assume* a solution of 
$$Y= \mathrm{Const}\cdot t^n $$
then get $Y^2$ and $Y''$ and plug into 
$$Y’’ = \mathrm{Const} /Y^2$$
you will find that $n$ has to be 2/3 to satisfy the eqn! What’s up with that? Lots slower than $t^2$ dependence.

Have I stumbled on a genuine “slow” solution to free fall that might have great cosmological implications? Or simply that my mind doesn’t accelerate as fast as it once did?

Comment: You found a solution to an equation of motion with acceleration dependent on position.  You're trying to compare to an equation of motion when acceleration is constant.

Comment: Err, but $at^2+bt+c $ isn't a solution to $y^{\prime\prime}=Cy^{-2} $. What are you talking about?

Comment: You can't ignore the complementary solution, otherwise you can't make the initial velocity zero without making the whole solution zero.  A particular solution by itself is *not* the complete solution.

Answer (score 3):

The $Y=at^2+vt+y_0$ solution is for constant acceleration, so isn't exact for $y$-dependent forces but is instead an approximation we use when the distance between the masses doesn't vary much. (For example, if I throw a ball on Earth, the ball's about $6.4\times 10^6\text{m}$ from Earth's centre of mass; going a few metres in the air is negligible.)

What you've done is to investigate the $y$-dependence, but a quadratic approximation oof $y$ is still possible; it's just a parabola tangent to the true curve at some typical value for $t$.

However, a $t^{2/3}$ solution is only physically relevant if the motion is $1$-dimensional, say if you dropped the mass $m$ from a very large altitude to fall vertically, with no horizontal momentum. By contrast, [analysis of a planetary orbit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler_problem) requires us to work in $2$ spatial dimensions (not $3$ because angular momentum conservation confines the mass-$m$ body to a plane). The result is a conic section, which again admits tangent parabolas.

Comment: Well, I’m Not calculating an orbit with any angular dependence—just dropping a point mass in a 1/ r^2 force field  and a T^2/3 dependence satisfies newton or coulomb but they never to my knowledge agreed it did! Of course it’s quite UN physical to say the least, but barring that, it appears to be an exact solution to the 1/r potential! Still puzzled!!

Comment: "[...] they never to my knowledge [...]", you said it all:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_fall#Inverse-square_law_gravitational_field

You found a particular solution for the exact case and were only aware of the solutions of the approximated case. Note that getting a free fall time $t(y) \propto \sqrt{y^3}$ is somewhat equivalent to having a position $y(t) \propto t^{2/3}$ ($\propto$ means "proportional to").

Comment: @WoodyPaul It's not unphysical at all. It might seem counter intuitive, but if you consider that the acceleration of the particle is smaller at higher heights, it makes a lot of physical sense that the time should be longer than if the acceleration was a constant equal to the surface gravitational effect.  Now, what is the Constant that goes with the $T^{2/3}$? That's very important, too!

Comment: @BillN As a full solution, $cT^{2/3}$ is pretty clear non-physical. In particular, $y(0)=0$ and $y^\prime(0)=\pm\infty$.

Comment: @Chris I agree. See my comment on the original question. Particular solutions by themselves are never the place to finish. They don't satisfy boundary conditions. My point is that a $t^{2/3}$ behavior as part of the total solution isn't patently non-physical.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from what J.G. said in their answer, you've stumbled upon a common error in mathematics: if you assume that a solution of a particular form exists, you get nonsense results if the solution is not, in fact, of that form. The question [Will assuming the existence of a solution ever lead to a contradiction?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2582488/will-assuming-the-existence-of-a-solution-ever-lead-to-a-contradiction/2583121) on the Mathematics Stack Exchange has a good number of examples for problems where assuming a solution exists leads to a contradiction, and a similar pitfall is assuming that a solution is of a particular form.

In particular, in this problem if you assume that the solution is of the form $at^n$, then you can show that the solution is $at^{\frac{2}{3}}$. But then you run into the issue that it is impossible to satisfy your initial conditions. Say $y(0)=y_0$ and $y^\prime(0)=0$. Then we have:

$$ y(0)=y_0=a\left(0\right)^{\frac{2}{3}}=0 \rightarrow y_0=0\rm~~~~~(Contradiction!) $$

$$ y^\prime(0)=0=at^{\frac{2}{3}} \rightarrow a=0 $$

Since we've reached a contradiction, that tells us that our assumption (that the solution can be written in the form $at^n$) is simply incorrect.